# Linux: Run a shell command remotely and print result

Tags: linux

I want to create a script that runs shell commands on a remote Linux machine and print out the result. Some thing like a "run once" SSH. Or for those familiar with Android development, something like "adb shell". For example, I want to run "ls" on my remote machine and display the results on the local host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported directly by ssh:

```
ssh [options] [user@]hostname [command]
```

eg

```
ssh user@host ls
```

If not command is given an interactive shell is usually run by default.